# Different behavior of KVM running status on physical KVM host and VM based KVM host

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, esx

I have an automation script that checks the running status of a KVM and does some action based on it. When I installed KVM using virt-install on a physical host the initial status of KVM ("Trying_a_nw_one" in this case) is "running" :-

```
 $virsh --quiet list
 6     kbUBU2                         running
 7     kbUBU3                         running
 9     kbUBU4                         running
 11    kbUBU5                         running
 12    Trying_a_nw_one                running
```

After some time the status automatically becomes "shut off" and this is what I expect in my script.
The problem happens when I create KVM using virt-install( same arguments ) on a KVM host which is again a VM running on ESX7.0. The initial status is "running" but it never changes. This makes the script behave differently.
Can anyone help to understand why KVM status is different in these two scenarios and how can I achieve consistent behaviour?
Ubuntu version is same in both case:-

```
 $lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
    Release:        14.04
    Codename:       trusty
```

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: ps:  I hope that system is kept offline... your details highlight you're well behind on applying security fixes (*even before EOSS was reached, Ubuntu 14.04 was at [14.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/08/ubuntu-14-04-6-lts-released/) but your details have you not applying fixes since 2016 if not before*)